# static route configuration issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two instances running in AWS in the same subnet.

- VM1 - 10.10.2.208
- VM2 - 10.10.2.136

I have configured route in VM1 as follows:

```
20.20.20.0      10.10.2.136     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

When I ping `20.20.20.3` from VM1, I can't see any ping request tcpdump in VM2. Could you please let me know any thing additionally to be done in AWS.

my tcpdump command as follows:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -n host 10.10.2.208
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify Below things

- In the route table of VM1 make sure there is local entry like vpc range is routed to local.
- Ping is a ICMP protocol so in VM2 security group VM1 IP/Security should be whitelisted for ICMP protocol
- Check for any deny rules in outbound of VM1 and inbound VM2 subnet's ACL.
- Check Rules of firewalls like iptables.